# Windows XP xcopy files with extensions recursively

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have a single-line script that copies all ".ext1" files from current folder to destination folder recursively:

```
xcopy *.ext1 D:\dest /s /d /y
```

It works perfectly.

Now I want to copy all *.ext2 as well. Instead of copy-pasting (that works fine):

```
xcopy *.ext1 D:\dest /s /d /y
xcopy *.ext2 D:\dest /s /d /y
```

I want to use a `for` command:

```
for %%f in (*.ext1 *.ext2) do xcopy %%f D:\dest /s /d /y
```

but it does not work:

1. It does not copy subdirs of source folder
2. It does not copy files with names with spaces like "read me.ext1"

I tried to use a `/R` key:

```
for /R %%f in (*.ext1 *.ext2) do xcopy %%f D:\dest /s /d /y
```

but it resulted in copying subdir source files into the root folder of dest. And names with spaces did not go.

What is a correct form of the `for` command would be?

Comment: for use with filenames with spaces use `...xcopy "%%f%" ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
for %%f in (.ext1 .ext2) do xcopy *%%f D:\dest /s /d /y
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell your only option **is** to call xcopy multiple times. If you want to have some kind of code-reuse I see two options:

Define the paramters as variables and use them:

```
set dest=d:\dest
set options=/s /d /y

xcopy *.ext1 %dest% %options%
xcopy *.ext2 %dest% %options%
```

or create a sub-program to do the copying:

```
call :do_copy ext1
call :do_copy ext2

goto :eof

:do_copy
   xcopy *.%1 d:\dest /s /d /y
   goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include wildcards in a regular `for` because they will always get expanded (or ignored if there is no match). If Endoro's answer doesn't work for you, you can read the list of wildcards from a file, or from the output of a command. Example:

```
for /f %%f in ('echo *.ext1 ^& echo *.ext2') do xcopy %%f D:\dest /s /y
```